# PHP - Upload images to FTP directory and then Display images uploaded only from directory

Tags: php, image, forms, ftp

i simply want that after i upload an image using form file upload, it will display those images on the next page. The images are uploaded to a folder on the ftp. i have looked everywhere but cant seem to find the right solution.

this is the HTML code for uploading image (image.php):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_1" type="file" /><br />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_2" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
</form>
```

Here's the PHP code on the next page (upload.php):

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "localhost";
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

if(@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "connected as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
  }
else {
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}
$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["name"];
$file2 = $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["name"];

$remote_file_path = "/2013/img/".$file;
$remote_file_path2 = "/2013/img/".$file2;

ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile_1"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path2, $_FILES["uploadedfile_2"]["tmp_name"],FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";
?>
```

Above is only the Upload code and I don't know what Php code I need to use for Displaying the images, but typically, I'd like to echo these two images on Upload.php. Is there a way that this code can predict what images were uploaded?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete script you can try.

When the user uploads something on PHP, that something goes to a temporary directory with a temporary name. You should therefore move the file away from there to a desired location. That's what the `move_uploaded_file()` in the script does. Also, for the images to show, that path must be available to your web server, which would mean under the `public_html` directory. And for PHP to be able to move the files there once they're uploaded, the directory must be writable. I've added some code to create a writable directory called `uploads` in the directory of the current script.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php 
// The HTML beginning tags must be there or the output won't render 
// as a web page

// Local path for storing the files, under the directory of this file
$local_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads';
// Create the directory if it doesn't exist
if ( ! is_dir( $local_path ) ) {
    mkdir( $local_path );
}
// Make the directory writable
if ( ! is_writable( $local_path ) ) {
    chmod( $local_path, 0777 );
}

// Loop through the uploaded files
foreach ( $_FILES as $ul_file ) {
    // Check for upload errors
    if ( $ul_file['error'] )
        die( "Your file upload failed with error code " . $ul_file['error'] );
    // Set a new file name for the temporary file
    $new_file_name = $local_path . '/' . $ul_file['name'];
    // Move the temporary file away from the temporary directory
    if ( ! move_uploaded_file( $ul_file['tmp_name'], $new_file_name ) )
        die( "Failed moving the uploaded file" );
    // Store the local file paths to an array
    $local_file_paths[] = $new_file_name; 
}

// Now do your FTP connection
$ftp_server     = "localhost";
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   = "xxx";
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
if ( @ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password) ) {
    echo "<p>Connected as $ftp_username @ $ftp_server</p>";
} else {
    die( "Could not log in as $ftp_username\n" );
}

// Loop through the local filepaths array we created
foreach ( $local_file_paths as $local_file_path ) {
    // The remote file path on the FTP server is your string + 
    // the base name of the local file
    $remote_file_path = "2013/img/" . basename( $local_file_path );
    // Put the file on the server
    ftp_put( $conn_id, $remote_file_path, $local_file_path, FTP_BINARY );
    echo "<p>Uploaded a file to $remote_file_path</p>";
}
// Close the connection
ftp_close( $conn_id );

echo "<p>Connection closed. Your images are here:</p>";

// Loop through the file paths again and output an HTML IMG element for each
foreach ( $local_file_paths as $local_file_path ) {
    echo "<img src='$local_file_path' alt='Your uploaded file' />";
}
// Final HTML tags
?> </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the HTTP POST upload from your user, the files go to a temporary directory under a temporary name. The actual file names on your server are contained in `$_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['uploadedfile_2']['tmp_name']`. (The `['name']` is the original file name on the user's computer.) You should then check for upload errors, move the files away from the temporary directory, and then you can put them via FTP. Finally, you can output a HTML IMG element.

```
// Check for errors
if ( $_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['error'] )
    die( "Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['error'] );

// Set a new path for the file. Use the original file name.
$new_path = '/a/writable/path/on/your/system/' . $_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['name']; 

// Move the file away from the temporary directory
if ( ! move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['uploadedfile_1']['tmp_name'], $new_path ) ) {
    die( "Failed moving the uploaded file" );
}
// Put the file on the FTP connection established before
// Use the FTP_BINARY type for image files
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $new_path,FTP_BINARY);

// After closing the connection, output an IMG element
// This works if your $new_path is readable by the web server
echo "<img src='$new_path' alt='Your uploaded file' />";
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. I think I am doing something wrong. Can't post my code here cos its limiting characters. Is there anyway you could please combine the php for me. Also, I'm confused with '/a/writable/path/on/your/system/'.. what path should I put here?

Comment: OK, I wrote a complete script for you in another answer. These were just examples, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php 

// The HTML beginning tags must be there or the output won't render 
// as a web page
if ($_POST) {
    // Local path for storing the files, under the directory of this file
    $local_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploads';
    // Create the directory if it doesn't exist
    if (!is_dir($local_path)) {
        mkdir($local_path);
    }
    // Make the directory writable
    if (!is_writable($local_path)) {
        chmod($local_path, 0777);
    }

    // Loop through the uploaded files
    foreach ($_FILES as $ul_file) {
        // Check for upload errors
        if ($ul_file['error']) {
            die("Your file upload failed with error code " . $ul_file['error']);
        }
        // Set a new file name for the temporary file
        $new_file_name = $local_path . '/' . $ul_file['name'];
        // Move the temporary file away from the temporary directory
        if (!move_uploaded_file($ul_file['tmp_name'], $new_file_name) ) {
            die("Failed moving the uploaded file");
        }
        // Store the local file paths to an array
        $local_file_paths[] = $new_file_name; 
    }

    // Now do your FTP connection
    $ftp_server     = "server";
    $ftp_username   = "username";
    $ftp_password   = "password";
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password)) {
        echo "<p>Connected as $ftp_username @ $ftp_server</p>";
    } else {
        die("Could not log in as $ftp_username\n");
    }

    // Loop through the local filepaths array we created
    foreach ($local_file_paths as $local_file_path) {
        // The remote file path on the FTP server is your string + 
        // the base name of the local file
        $remote_file_path = basename( $local_file_path );
        // Put the file on the server
        ftp_put( $conn_id, $remote_file_path, $local_file_path, FTP_BINARY );
        echo "<p>Uploaded a file to $remote_file_path</p>";
    }
    // Close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);

}

?> 
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="img_upload.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_1" type="file" /><br />
        Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile_2" type="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```